# How to integration-test a parachain

Tags: parachain, testing

Parachains can conveniently be tested locally with polkadot-launch to ensure a specific runtime release will produce blocks and perform e2e tests.

Is there an example of how to do these kinds of tests in github actions automatically?

Answer (score 5):

`polkadot-launch` is being deprecated in favor of [zombienet](https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet).

You can find some examples on [polkadot](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/zombienet_tests) and [cumulus](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/zombienet_tests), although some might be depending on Parity internal infrastructure and you won't necessarily get the full picture.

Also, check [parachains-integration-tests](https://github.com/paritytech/parachains-integration-tests). It is the tool Parity uses for Common Good Parachains. You can find the tests here: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/master/parachains/integration-tests

Comment: About `parachains-integration-tests`, just to mention that the tests `./examples` are expecting a modified Polkadot/Kusama runtimes with `pallet_sudo`. The reason for that is to bypass Governance when a `root` origin is required.